# Preloading the next (or previous) page in ViewPager

Tags: android

I have managed to show the edges of the next and previous pages by setting a negative page margin. However, the problem is that if I scroll page 1 to the left such that now page 2 is in the center, like so:

```
0 - [ 1 ] - 2   --->  1 - [ 2 ] - 3
```

, then page '3' is loaded ONLY after 2 arrives at the center and the swipe ends. This causes a jarring "appear" of page '3' (instead of smoothly sliding in).

How do I have page '3' loaded so that animation is smooth?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Have you tried `setOffscreenPageLimit()` on `ViewPager`?

Comment: I guess it was dumb to ask the question before exploring the API doc completely. I had stumbled across this API a few minutes before I checked your reply, while reading the source of ViewPager :P .

Comment: Please help me i want to show 3 view in my view pager but i am not able to make it at this point in time and i have no hint.

Comment: setOffscreenPageLimit(1)   it is useless!